# XSLT - Ignore case while matching

Tags: xslt

I have an XML "1.0" XSLT transformation where I need case insensitive matching.
I am using the following to rename "my_col" to "renamed_col",

```
<xsl:template match="my_col">
    <renamed_col>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </renamed_col>
</xsl:template>
```

This works fine if I use "my_col", but fails when I use "My_Col". 
I need to match this column irrespective of the letter case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by Priyansh Goel will cover *all* possible case variations (except with names that use characters other than those listed). However, if you know what variations to expect, you could make this simpler (and faster) by listing them explicitly, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="my_col | My_Col">
    <renamed_col>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </renamed_col>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the resolution. But I have no idea of the source XML file. So it will be better for me to handle all possible variations.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 <xsl:template match="*[ translate( local-name(),
                                         'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                         'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                        ) = 'my_col']">
```

Comment: this is removing the column from the output instead of renaming it

Comment: What do you mean by removing the column?